# compatibility of Bluetooth 4.2 and 5.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some questions about Bluetooth compatibility.

I have a MCU with Bluetooth 4.0 and a Android Smartphone with Bluetooth 4.1 .

and I have created an application that connects those two devices.

And this works well.

If I use a Android Smartphone with Bluetooth 4.2 or Bluetooth 5.0, 
Does this work well?

Comment: Probably you have to add the support for `BLE`

Comment: What support for BLE is required?..  Is there an official Android site to refer to?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I did not find the answer I wanted..
I have already created an Android application.
This Android application works well on an Android smartphone with Bluetooth 4.0 or 4.1 and an MCU with Bluetooth 4.0.

My question is, "Can this Android application communicate with a device that has a mcu with Bluetooth 4.0 on a smartphone with Bluetooth 4.2 or 5.0?"..